# Wordpress blog in the same domain as a SPA, is it possible?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

We have a React application hosted on our www.domain.com. Every route that goes through www.domain.com/* is handled by our React application.

Is there a way to config the route www.domain.com/blog to take the user to our WordPress blog? (without going through the React app).

Our website is served statically through CloudFront and we use Route53 for the DNS configuration.

Comment: Yes. Use Nginx or other reverse proxy.

Comment: @estus any pointers to some example? Remember that the site is hosted on Cloudfront so I don't have a server running there where I can setup nginx